# Added the missing reference to the project, but types are still not recognized. Why?

Tags: assemblies, system.data.oracleclient

I am trying to create a simple code sample that access an oracle database, in a Web Api 2 project.

Since `OracleClient` dll is not available "by default" (if I understand it right, upon creating a new project the targeting framework subset is not the full framework dll set), I added a reference to System.Data.OracleClient.

The references to the dll's types such as `OracleConnection`, `OracleCommand` and so are all recognized by VS, just like intelisense shows `OracleClient` after typing `System.Data`.

A build however raises an error stating

```
The type or namespace name 'OracleClient' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

The **runtime version** (v4.0.30319) and **version** (4.0.0.0) are exactly the **same** as, say, System.Data, automatically loaded when upon creation.

What is wrong ?

Comment: Unless you are not using System.Data dll you should remove it (not just the using I mean the reference). If you are using the dll in your project, try to move all your logic for Oracle to a new project and then remove the system.data.dll again.

Comment: @kms: your suggestion did not help

Answer (score 1):

Adding a reference to a new dll requires **restarting** visual studio.